# Clear failed modules in Dojo module loader?

Tags: dojo

When you load with Dojo's require a module with the wrong module url (mid), it creates an error (timeout) each time you use require(not loaded yet modules) again, regardless you loaded another module successfully afterwards.

Is there a way to clear that errors? Those failed modules seem to be permanent somewhere in dojo.js and they don't seem to be accessible through an API.

ps: I'd be happy even with a core hack to get rid of them.

Comment: Which modules are you talking about? The require API is all or nothing. There should never be a case where a module doesn't load, otherwise the require shouldn't successfully callback.

Comment: Any sort of module! I can't find anything in the internet which says: modules have to be in place when loading. Where did you read this?  However, all I am asking is to clear the errors, nothing else.

Comment: I'm asking for a list of the Dojo modules that are timing out for you.

Comment: Oh, now I see. No, its all about custom modules. I am trying also to wrap require into a regular promise where failed modules will trigger an error which I want to cleanup properly. I agree that most of the time you won't need this but in larger applications where user code is placed inside regular AMD modules, you definitely need this. Thanks again.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this isn't the use case require was designed for. It's supposed to load a module once and cache it for reuse. If there's a possibility a module won't exist during runtime (which means there is probably a bad design decision somewhere), you can use `dojo/request` to check for the existence of a file on the server before requiring it.

Comment: Can you give a code example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yeah well, first catching and cleaning require and define calls, and then wrapping it as regular promise or deferred. But you're right. I try better to feed  require.cache with valid modules directly.thanks!

Comment: The author of require-js, extended his package "alameda" for having require  calls as regular promises. This solves it for me and is way better than messing with global error handlers. https://github.com/requirejs/alameda/issues/8#event-532143836